# Wordpress generate <img class="someclass alignleft"> instead of <img class="someclass" align="left" />

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just upgraded my wordpress site to 3.6.1. Then I realize that there's something wrong with the  tag. It generates incorrect html  tag which is:

```
<img class="wp-image-24 alignleft" alt="some_text" src="path-to-uploads/2013/09/somefile.jpg" width="100" height="125" />
```

which is supposted to be

```
<img class="wp-image-24" align="left" alt="some_text" src="path-to-uploads/2013/09/somefile.jpg" width="100" height="125" />
```

It only happen if I use the theme I create myself, but if I use Wordpress default theme like Twenty Thirty, this issue doesn't happen. Then I suspect there's something wrong with my theme. But I completely don't have any idea what causes it. Please anybody give me a clue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well guess what? That's the right way to do it. You shouldn't be using `align="left"` anymore, that attribute is deprecated since HTML5. You can read more about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp

So what WordPress basically does it adding the class `alignleft` if they want something left aligned. The basic CSS for alignleft is:

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Each theme can of course chose their own styling for alignleft, but usually it doesn't vary very much.

Read more: [WordPress Core CSS](http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes)

Answer (score 0):

Although its strange this doesn't occur on certain themes. It was expunged from wordpress' core CSS

```
img class="wp-image-24 alignleft"
```

Will achieve the same as

```
img class="wp-image-24" align="left"
```

See all of the [WordPress Generated Classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS)